# Rails: how to use CollectionSerializer for custom array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, active-model-serializers

I have an array that merged from many sources. For example:

```
        list_items = []
        items.each do |item|
          # I convert details list to array by using to_a
          list_items.push(item.item_details.to_a)
        end
```

Then I use that custom array and serialize:

```
        {
            data: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(
                list_items,
                serializer: ItemSerializer)
        }
```

Then I meet exception:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for Array:0x007fcee2290460)

If above code I don't use `to_a` but :

```
          list_items.push(item.item_details)
```

I will meet different exception:

> undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fcee67ae

Please explain for me why I meet this exception and how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer for my problem. My problem because I insert an array to an array. Ruby will create two-dimensional array so my `CollectionSerializer` cannot work at this case. (because I assume that is one-dimensional array). So here is the fixing:

```
    list_items = []
    items.each do |item|
      # I convert details list to array by using to_a
      # list_items.push(*item.item_details.to_a)

      # using * operator before array for flattening array
      list_items.push(*item.item_details)
    end
```

After this, everything works like a charm.

```
    {
        data: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(
            list_items,
            serializer: ItemSerializer)
    }
```

You can get more detail here: [unary operator for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-this-ruby-code)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. try it out

```
{
 data: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(list_items, each_serializer: ItemSerializer).to_json 
}
```

Comment: ArraySerializer has been replaced by CollectionSerializer in Rails 5