# Run Ruby block for each item of array passed as an argument

Tags: ruby

Struggling with this simple task. Not an expert at Ruby:

```
  def self.send_mass_sms(*number, message)
    *number.each do |n|
      @client.messages.create(
        from: ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'],
        to: "+370#{n}",
        body: "#{message}"
      )
    end 
  end
```

number is `string[]` - ["657765", "765475"]

Error:

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

Comment: "**Struggling** with this **simple** task."---looks self-contradictory.

Comment: Try to understand when to use `*numbers` and `numbers`. Follow the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/918479/787980

Comment: @sawa - self-contradictory is also when people comes here to help, but doesn't do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `*` sign

```
def self.send_mass_sms(*number, message)
  number.each do |n|
    @client.messages.create(
      from: ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'],
      to: "+370#{n}",
      body: "#{message}"
    )
  end
end
```